# Is there a window zoom shortcut on android 10 without using physical buttons?

Tags: lg, android-10

On android 9 I was able to utilize the "window zoom" vision accessibility feature by triple tapping on the home button to bring it up. On android 10 I cannot find that option. The only shortcut I can find for accessibility settings is to press the volume up and power button at the same time. Is there any way to get window zoom by tapping virtual buttons on android 10?

To clarify, there is a zoom feature that magnifies the whole screen by triple tapping anywhere on the screen, but I do not like this feature as it causes apps with virtual buttons like calculators to become laggy and less responsive. I specifically want the "window zoom" feature for when I play a game with text that is too small at times and I would like to activate it in-game without using the volume and power buttons.

Edit: My phone is an LG G7 thinQ

Comment: Is there no setting named Magnification?

Comment: @Firelord I get no search result in settings for "Magnification"